# Retrieving value on Spinner with multiple arrays from shared Preferences

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I am having difficulties on retrieving spinner values from shared preferences.
The error message is:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
>   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>   at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:66)
>   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
>   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
>   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
>   at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:555)
>   at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:503)
>   at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:465)

I have two spinners, the first spinner is for STATE and the second spinner is for REPRESENTATIVES.

Whatever State I choose, the Representative spinner will populate an `arraylist` contained on the XML file.

Once the user selected a Representative it saves on `sharedPreferences` by position.
And it also retrieves and set the Representative's spinner selection based on the saved position.

Now HERE comes the problem:

*Some State has small number of representatives and some are a lot, like for example California and Alaska.

If I choose California and choose a representative number 5 the position value of the second spinner will be saved as no. 5.

If I change my State to Alaska  the Representative's spinner will attempt to retrieve the current value that is saved on the `sharedPreferences` but it crashes because there is only one representative on Alaska which with a max value position of 1.

So please, tell me what to do on this. I can't find a way to fix it.
What I want to do is whenever I choose a different State it refreshes or update the second spinner(Representative) selection value to a default which is 0 and saved the new selected(Representative) spinner value selection to `sharedPreferences`.

HERE is my Activity Code:

```
public class Location extends AppCompatActivity {

// Wigets - GUI
Spinner statespinner;
Spinner RepresentativeSpinner;
Button btnsubmit;
TextView Senators_Location;
TextView Capital_Location;
TextView Governor_Location;
TextView txtOrigin;
int arrayId;
ArrayAdapter < CharSequence > Rep_Spinner_Adapter;


@
Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

// Initialize Spinners
statespinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.State_spinner);
RepresentativeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Representatives_spinner);
btnsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.state_county_button);
Capital_Location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Capital_Location);
Governor_Location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Governor_Location);
Senators_Location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Senators_Location);
txtOrigin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_20);


ArrayAdapter < CharSequence > adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.State_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
statespinner.setAdapter(adapter);

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
int State_spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceState", -1);
if (State_spinnerValue != -1)
      statespinner.setSelection(State_spinnerValue);


statespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@
Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > adapter, View v, int position, long id) {


SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int state_choice = statespinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
String Senate_Selection = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditorState = sharedPref.edit();
prefEditorState.putString("Senators_Choice", Senate_Selection);
prefEditorState.putInt("userChoiceState", state_choice);
prefEditorState.apply();

String State_Item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
  
  
if (State_Item.equals("Select A State")) {
Senators_Location.setText(null);
Capital_Location.setText(null);
Governor_Location.setText(null);
arrayId = R.array.Blank_Rep_arrays;}

  
else if (State_Item.equals("Alabama")) {
          Capital_Location.setText(getString(R.string.Alabama_Capital));
          Governor_Location.setText(getString(R.string.Alabama_Governor));
          Senators_Location.setText(getString(R.string.Alabama_Senators));
arrayId = R.array.Alabama_arrays;}

else if (State_Item.equals("Alaska")) {
          Capital_Location.setText(getString(R.string.Alaska_Capital));
          Governor_Location.setText(getString(R.string.Alabama_Governor));
          Senators_Location.setText(getString(R.string.Alaska_Senators));
arrayId = R.array.Alaska_arrays;} 

else if (State_Item.equals("American Samoa")) {
          Capital_Location.setText(getString(R.string.American_Samoa_Capital));
          Governor_Location.setText(getString(R.string.American_Samoa_Governor));
          Senators_Location.setText(getString(R.string.American_Samoa_Senators));
arrayId = R.array.American_Samoa_arrays;}

else if (State_Item.equals("Arizona")) {
          Capital_Location.setText(getString(R.string.Arizona_Capital));
          Governor_Location.setText(getString(R.string.Arizona_Governor));
          Senators_Location.setText(getString(R.string.Arizona_Senators));
arrayId = R.array.Arizona_Representatives_array;}


Rep_Spinner_Adapter =
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Location.this, arrayId, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        Rep_Spinner_Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        RepresentativeSpinner.setAdapter(Rep_Spinner_Adapter);

SharedPreferences sharedPrefRep = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
int Rep_spinnerValue = sharedPrefRep.getInt("userChoiceRep", -1);
if (Rep_spinnerValue != -1) RepresentativeSpinner.setSelection(Rep_spinnerValue);


// Showing selected spinner item
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected State: " + State_Item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}


@
Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});


RepresentativeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

@
Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > Rep_adapter, View v, int position, long id) {


SharedPreferences sharedPrefRep = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
String representatives_item = Rep_adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
int Rep_choice = RepresentativeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditorRep = sharedPrefRep.edit();
prefEditorRep.putString("RepSelected", representatives_item);
prefEditorRep.putInt("userChoiceRep", Rep_choice);
prefEditorRep.apply();


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected Representatives: " + representatives_item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

@
Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


});

}

public void onDestroy() {

super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Here is my Array Representative XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="Representatives_string">Choose Your Representatives</string>

<string-array name="Blank_Rep_arrays">
<item>Select A Representatives</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Alabama_arrays">
<item>Select A Representatives</item>
<item>#1: Bradley Byrne</item>
<item>#2: Martha Roby</item>
<item>#3: Mike Rogers</item>
<item>#4: Robert Aderholt</item>
<item>#5: Mo Brooks</item>
<item>#6: Gary Palmer</item>
<item>#7: Terry A. Sewell</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Alaska_arrays">
<item>Select A Representatives</item>
<item>Don Young (At Large)</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="American_Samoa_arrays">
<item>Select A Representatives</item>
<item>Amata Radewagen (At Large)</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Arizona_Representatives_array">
<item>Select A Representatives</item>
<item>#1: Ann Kirkpatrick</item>
<item>#2: Martha McSally</item>
<item>#3: Raul Grijalva</item>
<item>#4: Paul A. Gosar</item>
<item>#5: Matt Salmon</item>
<item>#6: David Schweikert</item>
<item>#7: Ruben gallego</item>
<item>#8: Trent Franks</item>
<item>#9: Kyrsten Sinema</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: hey @thym, store and load `representative` position using `state name` as _key_ instead of `userChoiceRep`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I, will try. Thanks